# using redis in getServerSideProps results in error net.isIP is not a function

Tags: redis, next.js, server-side

Correct me if I am wrong but `getServerSideProps` is used to pre-render data on each render? If I use the standard `redis` npm module in `getServerSideProps` I get the error `net.isIP is not a function`. From what I have researched this is due to the client trying to use the `redis` functions.

I am trying to create an application to where session data  is saved in a `redis` key based on a cookie token. Based on the user Id a database is called and renders data to the component.  I can get the cookie token in `getServerSideProps` but I I run `client.get(token)` I  get the error `net.isIP is not a function` at runtime.

Am I not using `getServerSideProps` correctly or should I be using a different method / function? I am new to the whole Next.js world. I appreciate the help.

If I use the same functionality in an `/api` route everything works correctly.

```js
import util from 'util';
import client from '../libs/redis' // using 'redis' module

// ... my component here

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const get = util.promisify(client.get).bind(client);
  
  const name = await get('mytoken') // error `net.isIP is not a function`

  return {
    props: {
      name
    },
  }
}
```

```js
// redis.js
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();
 
client.on("error", function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});

module.exports = client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to `next` version `10.0.6` from `9.3` and I do not receive the error anymore.